# How to make Number.prototype.toLocaleString() accessible within VoiceOver?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, accessibility

We have discovered that on VoiceOver for iOs, the number "-$10" is read as "ten dollars" and in order for it to be picked up by VoiceOver, we need to format it as `$\u221210` or `$&minus;10`.

We've been excited by standardized localeformatting from the Javascript i18n library, but it looks like the default formatting is the first example above and is therefore not accessible in VoiceOver:

```
var number = -5; number.toLocaleString('en-CA', {style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD'});
// "-$5.00"
// needs to be "$−5.00"

var number = -5; number.toLocaleString('fr-CA', {style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD'});
// "-5,00 $"
// needs to be "−5,00 $"
```

Both those strings are read in VO as "5 dollars" unless the dash is replaced with the unicode minus symbol after the fact. I am writing a function to do that after the fact, but it feels messy, especially to try and account for every scenario. Furthermore in english, we need to transpose the `$` and `−`. Not to mention what happens when we need to support other locales. Is there a way to provide that option to localeString so that it is accessible out of the box?

I'm wondering if there are other approaches that might be more manageable in a large codebase to ensure data is accessible